# Case Creation-Email Notification From System email

Tags: email, case, servicecloud

After a case is created, we would like notify the contact about case creation. The users are selecting the flag "Send notification email to contact" which is sending a notification to the contact but the From address is user's email. Is there anyway to change this to systems email address??

I have seen workaround to change user's email in MySettings to system email and not sure that is good idea because we have many reps and everyone has to change their settings.

Finally I come to a conclusion that we need to workflow rule to send email notification where I can control from email address.

But just wondering any out of the box solution for this without workflow.

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score -1):

There is a setting in Case Support Settings - **Send Case Notifications from System Address**

Use this setting to specify that case comment, case attachment, and case assignment email notifications are sent from a system address. If you do not select this setting, case notifications will appear to be sent from the user or contact updating the case.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Hi, I have already have this setting enabled but notifications are sent from user's email address.

Comment: Seems like it is standard & we may have to use Auto response rules with Org wide email id OR Workflow rule with Org wide email id.